# javascript change and send multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript

H, I have 4 checkboxes that i need to set values when clicked and unclicked. I have code that works for the first one but struggling to make it work with the other 3?

The code is

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> Return journey required?</label>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="signs" id="signs"> Non sign written</label></div>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="disabled" id="disabled"> Disabled access</label></div>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="female" id="female"> Female driver</label></div>
```

and the js that works for the first on is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $("." + inputValue).toggle();

    if (this.checked){ 
        document.getElementById("return_required").value = "YES"; 
    } 
    else { 
        document.getElementById("return_required").value = "NO";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: From a quick glance, is it because you used `getElementById`, as you can only use the same ID once in a single HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Because they don't have a value like the first one. They have an id.

You are getting the input value and working on it, so if the input don't has a value, you won't be able to select it.

```
var inputValue = $(this).attr("value"); // Offending line, because only your first input has a value.
$("." + inputValue).toggle();
```

Comment: Ok, if i ad values to the other 3, how do i check and set them in the js script?

Comment: To be frank, don't really know what you are trying with that code xD I just see that when a checkbox is clicked, you toggle all the elements with class "value". You are not "toggling the value". So when you click the first element, that has a value "red", you are selecting all the elements in your page that have a class "red" a toggling them. When you select by adding a dot as first character, you are selecting by class: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @Jules Forgot to tag so you get notified.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to check the `name` of the clicked element using `this.name` and manually match it to the checkboxes, then code the logic for each checkbox. An example is provided below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $("." + inputValue).toggle();
    if (this.name == "colorCheckbox")
      if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("return_required").value = "YES";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("return_required").value = "NO";
      }
    else if (this.name == "signs") {
      console.log("signs"); // replace with logic
    } else if (this.name == "disabled") {
      console.log("disabled");  // replace with logic
    } else if (this.name == "female") {
      console.log("female");  // repalce with logic
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="colorCheckbox" value="red"> Return journey required?</label>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="signs" value="signs"> Non sign written</label></div>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="disabled" value="disabled"> Disabled access</label></div>
<div align="left"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="female" value="female"> Female driver</label></div>
<br>
<input id="return_required" value="NO"></input>
```